# UIImage to BitmapContext

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ipod

I want to convert a simple UIImage into BitmapContext, but I cannot find any tutorial to convert UIImage into BitmapContext. Kindly tell me how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this code help you

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(320, 400);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

[imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];



UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);
[data writeToFile:@"foo.png" atomically:YES];


 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil);///save image in phone

OR For Bitmap.

CGContextRelease(context);
context = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL,                                                     
                                image.size.width,
                                image.size.height,
                                8,    // bits per component
                                bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                colorSpace,
                                kCGImageAlphaLast
                                );
CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );                                                                      

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);
pixelData = CGBitmapContextGetData(context);
```

Comment: Hey I want to convert UIImage into BitmapContext & draw it on the screen. I dont want to save it on the album.

Comment: tell me what is pixel data? what is its type?

Comment: Please check this link : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextCreate